# Compare Array of Objects with Object in ES6

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-class

so basically I want to compare the object of array with another object and change its value. The data is fully dynamic so I can't use static keys.
here is my data

[image]

this new DATA is the one I want to add in the invoiceDATA

[image]

but the problem is that DOCDT is not static it can be dynamic so I cannot use static key name.

Thank you!!

Comment: With [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) you can get the keys of an object

Comment: can you give me code example ?

Comment: Please post actual code. Screenshots alone do not suffice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: no @Argee it does not, as i already told my keys and values are dynamic I cannot hardcode it

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, they aren't searchable for future readers and they are harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign(oldObj, newObj);` and it will assign all value from `new object` to `old object`. If property is not there then it will also create new properties.

```js
let newObj = { DOCDT: '6/21/20' };
let oldObj = { DOCDT: '1/10/20', DOCNO: "", IREF1: "50" };

Object.assign(oldObj, newObj);
console.log(oldObj);
```

If `oldObj` is array of objects then use it like `oldObj.forEach(x => Object.assign(x, newObj));`.

```js
let newObj = { DOCDT: '6/21/20' };
let oldObj = [{ DOCDT: '1/10/20', DOCNO: "", IREF1: "50" }];

oldObj.forEach(x => Object.assign(x, newObj));
console.log(oldObj);
```